# What's the logic behind the color puzzles in Lilly Looking Through?

Tags: lilly-looking-through

In the final chapter, you have to

> change the color of the flowers from blue to red,

which requires the following steps:

> 1. The flowers are blue.
>  2. Send green color -> The flowers are now green.
>  3. Send blue color -> The flowers are now yellow. (The animation changes here, it looks like blue is "removed" from the flowers.)
>  4. Send orange color -> The flowers are now orange.
>  5. Send yellow color (by combining green and blue) -> The flowers are now red.

I discovered this more or less by trial and error. However, this is such a nicely done game with such attention to detail that I'm sure there is some logic behind it, which I just don't understand. Can someone explain it to me?

What I have tried:

- There are various walkthroughs available online, but they all just list the steps required to solve the puzzle, rather then explaining the mechanics behind it.
- I have looked at various additive and subtractive color charts, but the logic still eludes me. (In what color system do green and blue combine to yellow?)

Answer (score -2):

Okay, we have two places to store color, the flowers, and the pipe.

It seems like it works using a variation of the [RYB color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_color#Traditional_painting_(RYB)).

If you're apply a Secondary Color, Orange, Purple or Green, to a location, it overwrites whatever color's in the location.

If you're applying a Primary Color, Red, Yellow, or Blue, to a location, if the location is empty, or another Primary, it would overwrite the color, and if a secondary is already there, it subtracts the Primary from the Secondary.

So you would only need the last two steps?

Even if I'm wrong, gonna put this info here, so others can use it:

---

What I know, is that, for the flowers, where the left is the flower, and the right is the color added:

```
Blue + Green = Green
Green + Blue = Yellow
Yellow + Orange = Orange
Blue + Orange = Blue
Green + Orange = Orange
Green + Yellow = Blue
Blue + Yellow = Blue
Orange + Blue = Orange
Orange + Yellow = Red
```

For an empty pipe, where the colors are added first, and second, from left to right:

```
Orange + Blue = Orange
Orange + Green = Orange
Blue + Green = Green
Green + Blue = Yellow
Yellow + Orange = Orange
```

Comment: I guess I'm being downvoted 'cause I don't have the authoritative knowledge of having played the game? ... Mmm... I see... And yet I'm not seeing any better answers... But now, having a playthrough, I can guess at the mechanics more.

Comment: I suspected something similar, but, unfortunately, just starting with step 4 does not work. (I did not downvote, btw.)

Comment: @Heinzi - What happens if you do step 4, first? ... Didn't think you downvoted. Thanks for clarifying anyway. As OP, if you did downvote, I'd expect a comment.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the flowers stay blue.